# How to open Console during runtime [C++/Visual Studio]

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sdl-2

Currently, I'm developing an SDL application with Visual Studio. 
Right now, if I want to have the console open in order to view output, I must enter the "properties of the project > Linker > System > SubSystem > Console" in order to enable it. When I'm ready to export however, I disable it.

However, I was wondering if there's anyway to open (or even close) the console window during runtime. Specifically, I wish to be able to press a key while the application is running in order open the console and view output.

I've tried using `AllocConsole` from `windows.h`, but while it does open a console window, it does not appear to display the output that normally appears whenever I manually set the application to use a Console window.

(Alternatively, I've been thinking I could open a second SDL window and display all output there, but I have no idea how to stream all output from the application to itself. Probably not the most convenient solution, but would work also.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
if (::GetConsoleWindow() == NULL)
{
  if (::AllocConsole())
  {
    (void)freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    (void)freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    (void)freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

    SetFocus(::GetConsoleWindow());
  }
}
```

Right before using `printf`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! However, how would I go about closing it?

Comment: To detach, first `freopen` the standard streams to the "NUL" device, or simply close them, and then call `FreeConsole()`. Do not close the console window because that will terminate all processes attached to the console. (If you do close the window, if a process has a control handler, it gets a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, but if it doesn't exit on its own within 5 seconds, it gets terminated by Windows.)

Comment: `GetConsoleWindow` will also return `NULL` if the process is attached to a console that has no window, e.g. `CreateProcess` was called with the flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`. In this case, you can check `SetLastError(0);` `codepage = GetConsoleCP()`. If either the returned codepage is non-zero, or `GetLastError()` is not `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, then you need to detach and allocate a new console if you want to actually see output.